# How to search for regex pattern python

Tags: python

I am trying to create an error handler for an exercise where I check for correct input format. I looked at the docs and SO for examples but I am still here. I believe I am looking for: (there have been a few variations tried as well)

```
check_time = re.compile('^[0-1][0-9]:[0-5][0-9] ([A|a]|[P|p][M|m])')
```

but my test cases are failing.
Code calling for input from user:

```
import re

class CivilianTime:
    def __init__(self):
        # no error handling yet
        self.civ_time = input('Enter the time in (XX:XX A/PM) format.\n')
        check_time = re.compile('1[0-2]:[0-5][0-9] AM | 1[0-2]:[0-5][0-9] PM')
        if check_time != self.civ_time:
            self.civ_time = input('Enter the time in (XX:XX A/PM) format.\n')

    # if PM, strip time to numerical values and add 1200
    # if AM, strip time to numerical values
    def time_converter(self):
        if self.civ_time[-2] == 'P':
            strip_time = self.civ_time.strip(" PM")
            strip_time = strip_time.replace(':', '')
            strip_time = int(strip_time) + 1200
            print(strip_time)
        else:
            strip_time = self.civ_time.strip(' AM')
            strip_time = strip_time.replace(':', '')
            print(strip_time)


c = CivilianTime()
c.time_converter()
```

Result:

```
Enter the time in (XX:XX A/PM) format.
1212 am
Enter the time in (XX:XX A/PM) format.
1212pm
1212pm
```

I want to see it ask for the time again when the input is not in the desired format. It's running the function even when there's no space.
Unless there's a way for me to use `in`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mis-reading the docs,
https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

`You are on the right track.  When you use or`|`, you have to rewrite the entire expression.  So first match 1 hour at a time and simply test all the cases in multiple lines of code. Dont try to one liner it until you completely understand regex.

12:00 AM and 11:00 AM and 10:00 AM = `1[0-2]:[0-5][0-9] AM`
Now to match that for PM you have to or `|` the entire expression.
So, `matcher = '1[0-2]:[0-5][0-9] AM | 1[0-2]:[0-5][0-9] PM'`

Now match the remaining time with what you have learned! Hint: the rest of the hours start with 0.

Comment: I just don't get it. I've used compile before and I've done string manipulations, but why is this just not working at all in the way I expect it to? I've updated my code and I still keep failing to produce the expected result.

Comment: Well don't give up, you can do it.  For me to debug the regular expression before all else, i use print(re.match(regex,string)) if it matches you get an object returned to you. Baby steps